# Is it worthwhile to implement the Struts Framework without using JSPs?

Tags: struts, struts-1

This isn't a programming question exactly but is there any point in implementing a project using the Struts framework but using HTML and Javascript instead of JSPs? Management is forcing this and it seems like the functionality they want can be obtained using EL in Struts 2.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. JSPs are simply servlets with another syntax. Their goal is precisely to generate HTML and JavaScript. But indeed, using STruts without JSPs is like building a cinema without a screen.

Comment: I'd say it makes sense, but it's unclear if you're talking about Struts 1 as the question as tagged, or Struts 2 as in the question text. Using Struts 2 as the back end to deliver JSON to a client-side framework is perfectly acceptable, although I'd tend towards something like Jersey if the *entire* app was designed like that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Struts 1 is the target framework, Struts 1.1 specifically.

Comment: JSP EL isn't tied to the backing framework but rather the application container. It's not really clear what you're asking, but Struts 1.1 *could* be used to deliver content suitable for a JavaScript-/client-side-based framework, but using a thoroughly antiquated, [end-of-lifed](http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html) framework like Struts 1.1 seems a Bad Idea, for JS *or* JSP sites.

Comment: EL in Struts 2 is OGNL, and it doesn't work without JSP and even withut Struts 2, the same is for JSTL EL, but combined together you could achieve a result.